# Ошибки в коде при решении уравнения переноса

Tags: c++-cli

Обновил содержание вопроса,так как некоторые моменты я сам понял и исправил.
И так есть следующие переменные:

```
hx (шаг по пространству)= 0.1

ht (шаг по времени) = 0.5

Nx (Количество шагов по пространству) = 10;

Nt (Количество шагов по времени) = 12;

wx[i] - массив содержит все шаги по пространству

wt[j] - массив содержит все шаги по времени

wht[j][i]-двумерный массив по которому будет строится результирующий график;
```

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

И так найдены несколько проблем:

1) Найдена в коде

```
for(int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)        
{
    wx[i+1] = wx[i] + hx;      //массив 
    wht[0][i] = fn(T, i * hx); //i * hx//Исправлено.
}
```

где `fn` это:

```
//Функция Хэвисайда - Начальное условие(Граничное условие) а начальное 0-1
public:static double fn(int T, double x)
{
    if (x >= 0) 
        return T;
    else if(x < 0)
        return 0;  
}
```

Я неправильно задаю начальные условия

Как вино на графике, среди безобразия там где-то видно общее решение "волна", но остальное там неправильно как раз из за того что я в коде неправильно задаю начальные условия

2) Циклы и массивы, а именно:

Идёт обращение к несуществующему элементу массива и следовательно возникают страшные цифры и скачок графика, но я изменить индексы не могу так как есть определённая формула.

```
for(int j = 0;j<Nt;j++)
{
    for(int i = 1;i<Nx-1;i++)///Исправлено с помощью ответа пользователя Denis Protopopov(и график немного изменился)
    {
        wht[j+1][i] = 
            ((wht[j + 1][i] - wht[j][i]) / ht) + a * ((wht[j][i+1] - wht[j][i]) / hx);
        wht[j+1][i] = -a * (ht * (wht[j][i+1] + wht[j][i]) / hx) + (wht[j][i]);
    }
}
```

Если я напишу вместо `i = 0`, `i = 2` или `j = 2`, то отрисовка графика будет ужасной.

Весь код:

```
public:static double qx0(double x)//ось пространства
           {
               if (x<=0) 
                   return 0;
               else
                   return x;
           }

    public:static double qt0(double t)//ось по времени
           {
               if (t<=0) 
                   return 0;
               else
                   return t;
           }

    public:static double fn(int T,double x)//Функция Хэвисайда - Начальное условие
           {
               if (x>=0)
                   return T;
               else if(x<0)
                   return 0;  
           }

public: void drawfunc(double T)
            {
                double xmin = -5;
                double xmax = 10;
                for(double x = xmin;x<xmax;x+=0.01)
                {       
            chart1->Series["Функция Хэвисайда"]->BorderWidth=3;
            chart1->Series["Функция Хэвисайда"]->Points->AddXY(x,fn(T,x));                       
                }                                       
            }


    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
             { 
                 ///-------Переменные для работы с разностными схемами
                 double a;//скорость переноса
                 double hx,ht;//шаги по пространству и времени
                 int Nx,Nt;//На сколько частей разбивае отрезок сетки
                 int T;//Входной параметр для искомой функции(Хэвисайд)
                 double wx[20]={0};//массив точек x
                 double wt[20]={0};//массив точек t
                 double wht[20][20]={0};// массив для разностной схемы(сетки) 
                 //double res[20][20]={0};//результирующий массив

                 if(textBox1->Text!="" && textBox2->Text!="" && textBox3->Text!="" && textBox4->Text!="" && textBox5->Text!="" && textBox6->Text!="" && textBox6->Text!="")
                 {

                     ///-----Ввод данных-----
                     a=Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
                     hx=Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
                     q=Convert::ToDouble(textBox3->Text);
                     ht=Convert::ToDouble(textBox4->Text);
                     Nx=Convert::ToInt32(textBox5->Text);
                     Nt=Convert::ToInt32(textBox6->Text);
                     T=Convert::ToInt32(textBox7->Text);

                     //----Построение сетки,узлов
                     for(int i = 0;i<Nx;i++)        
                     {
                         wx[i+1]=wx[i]+hx;//массив 
                         wht[0][i]=qx0(wx[i]);                       
                     }   

                     for(int j = 0;j<Nt;j++) //
                     {                                                       
                         wt[j+1]=wt[j]+ht;
                         wht[j+1][0] = qt0(wt[j+1]);                     
                     }


                     ///-----------------Вычисление основых формул с разностной схемой

                     for(int j = 0;j<Nt;j++)
                     {
                         for(int i = 1;i<Nx-1;i++)///Вывод формул wht[j+1][i] 
                         {                           
        wht[j+1][i]=((wht[j+1][i]-wht[j][i])/ht)+a*((wht[j][i+1]-wht[j][i])/hx);
        wht[j+1][i]=-a*(ht*(wht[j][i+1] + wht[j][i])/hx) + (wht[j][i])+ht*fn(wt[j],hx); 
                         }
                     }

                     //----Для записи в простой текстовый файл                  
                     String^ fileName = "results.txt";
                     StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
                     for(int j = 0;j<Nt;j++)    
                     {
                         for(int i = 0 ;i<Nx;i++)
                         {
                             sw->Write("{0} ",wht[j][i]);
                         }
                         sw->WriteLine();
                     }
                     sw->Close(); 


                     //Тестовые функции для отображения
                     drawfunc(T);// Вызов функции для рисования

                     ///---------------Построение графика                        

                              for(int j = 0;j<Nt;j++)
                     {
                          for(int i = 0;i<Nx-1;i++)
                         {  
                        chart2->Series["Series2"]->BorderWidth=3;           
                        chart2->Series["Series2"]->Points->AddXY(i,wht[j][i]);
                         }
                     }                                           
                 }
                 else MessageBox::Show("Ошибка!Не все поля заполнены!");
             }
```

Comment: На первый взгляд это что-то с математическим анализом связано, или геометрией графиков. Вы для несмышленых подскажите уже, ЧТО КОНКРЕТНО вы пытаетесь добиться в этом коде?

Comment: Математическая часть проверена и чисто формула запрограммирована правильно(уже проверяли)
Я хочу добиться корректного вывода графика.

Но проблема номер 1, мешает выводу графика и поэтому мне интересно узнать какие действия мне нужно сделать чтобы правильно задать начальные условия и работать с формулой.

Дело в том что я пытаюсь значение функции fn записать в массив где хранятся шаги по пространству,что в корне неправильно.

Comment: Пробег должен идти от 0 до N-1 for(int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) чтобы не выходить за границы массива.

Comment: а пробовали ли использовать возможности коммерческих мат.пакетов по генерации кода ? MATLAB Coder, Maple CodeGeneration и т.п.

Comment: разделите расчет, выборку данных для отрисовки графика (в нужном формате), а саму отрисовку отдайте какому-нибудь GNUPLOT или другому визуализатору -- если гарантировано что сам расчет правилен, то причина скорее всего в ошибочных индексах при выборке данных: например не в том порядке указываете индексы многомерных массивов

Comment: раз 10 просмотрел вопрос -- а где ссылка на пакет кода и образцы исходных данных и графика для этих данных ?

Comment: В основном цикле написано странное. Во-первых, результат первого присваивания не влияет на результат, поскольку значение `wht[j+1][i]` перезаписывается вторым присваиванием. Во-вторых, второе присваивание эквивалентно соотношению `(wht[j+1][i] - wht[j][i])/ht == -a * ( wht[j][i+1] + wht[j][i]) / hx`. Это с точностью до O(hx) эквивалентно `hx * du/dt = -2au` - жесткое дифференциальное уравнение. Напомню, что уравнение переноса, это `du/dt = -a*du/dx`. Прежде, чем решать с разрывным начальным условием, убедитесь, что у вас гладкая функция - синус, побежит в нужную сторону с нужной скоростью.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov да так оно и есть.

Эквивалентно.


Дело в том что по заданию мне это сказали выразить аналитически(я это сделал,проверили и сказали аналитически правильно - программируйте) я и запрограммировал её.

С sin(x) такая же проблема(так же отображается)-сейчас проверил
Плюс я 1-ое присваивание wht[j+1][i]  убрал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ответить, почему не бежит волна на графике, нужно сначала разобраться с численным методом, а лишь потом с кодом на C++. Теория численного анализа не входит в круг вопросов, которые обсуждаются на этом сайте, но краткая справка может пригодиться.

#### 1. Небольшое отступление, посвященное разностным схемам

Итак, мы ищем функцию u(x,t), которая является решением задачи Коши для дифференциального уравнения в частных производных

```
  d u       d u
  --- = - a ---       (1)
  d t       d x
```

с начальным условием

```
  u(x,0) = f(x)       (2)
```

Уравнение (1) называется *уравнением переноса*, поскольку решением нашей задачи является `u(x,t) = f(x-at)`. Это функция, график которой движется со временем вправо со скоростью `a`.

> Подставьте функцию f(x-at) вместо u в уравнение (1) и вычислите частные производные, чтобы проверить, что она действительно является решением.

Преподаватели учат студентов не искать лёгких путей, а решить это уравнение методом конечных разностей. Можно предложить несколько разностных аппроксимаций уравнения (1). Нам предлагается воспользоваться одной из них. Как вскоре выяснится, это очень неудачный выбор.

Итак, рассмотрим схему, в которой производная по `t` аппроксимируется разностным оператором `Dt u`.

```
    Dt u = (u(x,t+dt) - u(x,t))/dt.
```

Этот оператор обладает первым порядком аппроксимации.

Производную по `x` аппроксимируем разностным оператором `Dx u`

```
    Dx u = (u(x+dx,t) - u(x,t))/dx.
```

Получим

```
    Dt u = -a Dx u.
```

Специалистам по численному анализу хорошо известно, что эта схема обладает первым порядком аппроксимации по dt и dx, а также является *абсолютно неустойчивой*. Это означает, что любое малое возмущение эта схема увеличивает в геометрической прогрессии.

> Подставим вместо `u(x,t)` функцию `q^(t/dt) e^(ipx/dx)`. Подставив, увидим, что если эта функция является решением разностного уравнения, то |q| > 1, если `sin p/2 != 0`. То есть, любое малое возмущение такой формы будет расти при росте t. Этот способ исследования устойчивости разностных схем называется *методом фон Неймана*.

Итак, эта схема абсолютно неустойчива, следовательно не удовлетворяет условию теоремы Лакса, так что не стоит ожидать сходимости функции, рассчитанной по этой схеме, к решению исходной задачи для уравнения в частных производных.

Интересно, что если мы будем вычислять производную по `x` по формуле

```
   D'x u = (u(x,t) - u(x-dx,t))/dt,
```

то получим устойчивую схему.

#### 2. Постановка задачи на ограниченном интервале

Мы хотим искать решение не на всей числовой оси, а на ограниченном интервале  `[xmin,xmax]`. Для того, чтобы функция `f(x-at)` была решением нашей задачи, необходимо дополнить задачу следующими граничными условиями.

```
    u(xmin,t) = f(xmin - a*t)        (3)
    u(xmax,t) = f(xmax - a*t)        (4)
```

Теперь мы можем перейти к программированию метода решения задачи (1-4) на основе явных схем первого порядка аппроксимации.

#### 3. Программная реализация

Ниже приведена примерная реализация исключительно самого метода. Всё, что касается визуализации, решено отдельно.

Первый блок кода, это определение граничных условий.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double T = 1.0;
const double a = 0.5;

inline double f(double x){
        if (x>=0)
                return T;
        return 0;
}

inline double u0(double x){
        return f(x);
}

inline double u1(double xmin, double t){
        return f(xmin - a * t);
}

inline double u2(double xmax, double t){
        return f(xmax - a * t);
}
```

Следующий блок кода содержит функцию, вычисляющую решение и сохраняющую его в массив. Наша функция в качестве аргументов принимает параметры задачи - координаты границ расчётной области и ссылку на массив, в который нужно сохранить результат.

```
void run(double xmin,double xmax, double tmax, int N,double u[][M]){
        double ht = tmax/N;
        double hx = (xmax - xmin)/M;

        for(int i=0; i<N;i++){
                u[0][i] = u0(xmin + i*hx);
        }

        for(int j=0; j < N-1; j++){
                u[j+1][0] = u1(xmin,j*ht);
                for(int i=1; i<N; i++){
                        double dudx = (u[j][i] - u[j][i-1])/hx;
                        u[j+1][i] = -a * dudx * ht + u[j][i];
                }
        }
}
```

Здесь реализован вариант с устойчивой схемой -- разностным оператором `D'x`

#### 4. Результаты

На следующей картинке нарисованы значения функции `u(x,t)` при `a=0.5` и `t=0`, `t=5.0` и `t=10.0`.

[image: График решения, вычисленного с помощью схемы с разностью назад]

Видно, что волна не столько бежит, сколько размазывается в пространстве.

Теперь заменим основной цикл, на цикл, реализующий абсолютно неустойчивую схему, определенную оператором `Dx`.

```
    for(int j=0; j < N-1; j++){
            for(int i=0; i<N-1; i++){
                    double dudx = (u[j][i+1] - u[j][i])/hx;
                    u[j+1][i] = -a * dudx * ht + u[j][i];
            }
            u[j+1][N-1] = u2(xmax,j*ht);
    }
```

Результат будет выглядеть примерно так

[image: График решения, вычисленного с помощью схемы с разностью вперёд]

Этот результат совсем не похож на бегущую вправо ступеньку.

#### 5. Заключение

Надеюсь, что этот пример иллюстрирует, что прежде, чем искать ошибки в коде, необходимо изучить свойства алгоритма.

Comment: Глядя на ваш код я понимаю как я всё у себя усложнил

А скажите пожалуйста у меня и 1-ый цикл неустойчивость показывает.

xmax= как я понял это Nx у меня это число где у меня закончится ось по пространствук примеру 1
xmin= как я понял это 0
tmax= а это Nt у меня(то есть максимум оси по времени) наприме 1,2
N - это количество шагов по осям как я понимаю?
А вот M это некоторое число которое будет содержатся в моём массиве.

Comment: Не совсем так. Я запускаю run с `xmin=-5.0`, `xmax = 10.0` и `tmax = Nt * ht`. `N=Nt`, это число шагов по t, `M=Nx`. Массивы `wt` и `wh`, в моём коде отсутствуют - здесь несущественно, а `u` заменяет `wht`. @beginner

Comment: Я почти угадал кроме M.
Уже сейчас уже лучше показывает,но не до конца.

Последний вопрос
Структура цикла для вывода графика у вас наподобие такой?

for(int j=0;j<N-1;j++){
for(int i=1;i<N;i++){//Код вывода графика } }//Использую tChart.

Я ещё один цикл,3-ий,который отвечает за построение чисто точки координат x.

Comment: Чтобы не закрасить весь график ровным слоем, стоит выбрать несколько значений j, отвечающих разным моментам времени, например, j0 = 0, j1 = Nt/2, j2= Nt. И для каждого из этих моментов записать значения `wht[ j0 ][i]` для всех `i=0..Nx` в отдельный инстанс `TChartSeries`. Это можно оформить как пару вложенных циклов. Внешний пробегает по списку выбранных индексов j0, j1, j2. Внутренний - от 0 до N-1.

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж никто не желает разбираться с этим вопросом, то осмелюсь высказать свои соображения.

В вопросе не хватает части кода, а именно:

1. Не заданы значения всем элементам массивов `wx`, `wt` и `wht`. Когда объявляется массив, ему выделяется место в памяти и, если после объявления не задать значения элементам массива, то при обращении к ним получаешь то, что там оказалось. Отсюда и берутся эти "страшные" значения. ))
2. Где объявляется переменная `T` ??
3. Где объявляется переменная `a` ??

Несколько измененный код:

```
double hx = 0.1;    // Шаг по пространству
double ht = 0.5;    // Шаг по времени
int Nx = 10;        // Количество шагов по пространству
int Nt = 12;        // Количество шагов по времени
double wx[Nx];      // Массив содержит все шаги по пространству
double wt[Nt];      // Массив содержит все шаги по времени
double wht[Nt][Nx]; // Двумерный массив, по которому будет строится результирующий график

for (int i = 0, step = 0; i < Nx; i++, step += hx)
{
    wx[i] = step; // Заполняем массив. Каждый шаг больше предыдущего на hx.

    //wht[0][i] = fn(T, i * hx); — Непонятно назначение метода fn. Проще сделать так:
    wht[0][i] = (T < 0) ? 0 : i * hx;

    // В этом цикле заполняется только массив `wx` и первая строка массива `wht`, 
    // а где задаются значения остальных элементов массивов `wht` и `wt` ??
} 

for (int j = 0; j < Nt; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
    {
        // Если в данном цикле использовать индекс j+1 или i+1, то это обязательно вызовет 
        // ошибку, т.к. индекс выйдет за пределы массива. Ошибка как раз будет в конце 
        // перебора массива. Думаю, этим и вызваны возникновение "страшных цифр" и скачок 
        // графика.
        wht[j + 1][i] = ((wht[j + 1][i] - wht[j][i]) / ht) + a * ((wht[j][i + 1] - wht[j][i]) / hx);
        wht[j + 1][i] = -a * (ht * (wht[j][i + 1] + wht[j][i]) / hx) + (wht[j][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @beginner А вообще, хотелось бы увидеть весь проект целиком, ибо  из этих кусков кода не удается составить полную картину. Это какая-то лабораторная работа??

Comment: весь код добавил в тему.
Да лабораторная работа.