# Граничные условия и вывод графика

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

Продолжение этой темы [Ошибки в коде при решении уравнения переноса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625225).
Полученная информация мне помогла во многом,но появилась проблема в выводе графика.

Проблемный участок кода найден. Весь код не выкладываю так как проблема пока именно в этом блоке.

```
inline double u0(int T,double x)//Начальные условия
{
    return fn(T,x);
}

inline double u1(int T,double a,double xmin, double t)//Граничные условия-Проблема в этом коде
{
    return fn(T,xmin - a * t);
}

for(int i=0; i<Nx;i++)
{
    wht[0][i] = u0(T,xmin + i*hx);//Заполнение начальных условий 
}

for(int j=0; j < Nt-1; j++)//Заполнение граничных условий
{
    wht[j+1][0] = u1(T,a,xmin,j*ht);
}
```

Как видно на графике линии вместо того, чтобы оставаться и заканчиваться на своих координатах,они все уходят обратно в 0, хотя мне нужно чтобы они продолжались и оканчивались на своей линии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил координаты через блокнот и там одни 0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменил код:

```
inline double u1(double ht)//Изменил возвращаемое значение в проблемном методе
{
    return ht;
}

for(int i=0; i<Nx;i++)
{
    wht[0][i] = u0(T,xmin + i*hx);//Заполнение начальных условий
}

for(int j=0; j < Nt-1; j++)//Заполнение граничных условий
{
    wht[j+1][0] = qt(j*ht);
}
```

Код построения графика

```
 ///---------------Построение графика


for(int j = 0;j<Nt-1;j++)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<Nx;i++)//Было Nx
    {                 
        chart2->Series["Series1"]->BorderWidth=3;
        chart2->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(i,wht[j][i]);
    }
}
```

В результате в текстовом файле уже отображаются координаты по вертикали (0.4,0.8,1.2 и т.д.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но сам график стал ещё хуже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Учитывая что мне нужно подниматься вверх по `t(0.4,0.8,1.2)` я и возвращаю `ht` (то есть шаг) и он у меня отображается, но, увы, почему-то вместо продолжения графика линии всё равно идут в обратную сторону.

Здесь снова проблема, связанная с программированием.

Comment: Приведите коды построения графиков. Кажется, вместо `MoveTo` в некоторых местах происходит `LineTo`

Comment: @DNS добавил код,но у меня там идёт через построение через TChart

Comment: Перед циклом с заполнением через `AddXY` добавьте очистку через `Clear`. При самом заполнение отладчиком поймайте ситуацию когда точка имеет координаты, которые не должны быть на графике. Если я правильно понял, то, например `{0,0}`.

Comment: Вы в какой среде вообще программу пишите? Что-то я сомневаюсь в необходимости метки [tag:c++-cli] здесь.

Comment: @alexolut Microsoft Visual Studio 2012,с использованием Windows Forms

Comment: @beginner мой предыдущий комментарий про отладку всё равно в силе :)